# unable to open android project in eclipse..!

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, project

I have been using eclipse for quite some time for java programs.Recently i got interest in android app development,not that i have developed any app,but i want to do it.So i downloaded android sdk manager and installed all the tools that was suggested.I have seen many tutorials where they have mentioned steps to open an android project. 
The problem here is that when i follow these step i don't see any android option...
I open eclipse then i click on file,new and then others..after that i don't see android option.
please help i need it..thanks in advance :)

Comment: may be you had download wrong eclipse mean Java Eclipse without Android plugin. [Download it from here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)

Comment: that clearly says your SDK is not configured correctly

Comment: did you install the eclipse ADT plugin?

Comment: Follow this http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you have not installed the ADT plugins for android.

**Download the ADT Plugin**

- `Start Eclipse, then select Help > Install New Software.`
- Click **Add**, in the top-right corner.
- In the **Add Repository** dialog that appears,enter "**ADT Plugin**" for the Name and the following URL for the Location: **https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/**
- Click **OK**. If you have trouble acquiring the plugin, try using "http" in the Location
  URL, instead of "**https**" (https is preferred for security reasons).
- In the Available Software dialog, select the checkbox next to Developer
  Tools and click **Next**.
- In the next window, you'll see a list of the tools to be downloaded. Click **Next**.
- Read and accept the license agreements, then click **Finish**. If you get a security warning saying that the authenticity or validity of the software can't be established, click **OK**.
- When the installation completes, **restart Eclipse**.